# Moved Leaflet layer add to external file and layers stopped adding

Tags: node.js, leaflet, pug

I had working javascript code that added layers to a leaflet map in a jade file within a node.js express framework. I moved the javascript to a separate file and included it along with all the necessary passed variables

```
script(src='/javascripts/Chart.js')
script.
  var spreadsheetData =!{JSON.stringify(spreadsheetData)};
  var lat = !{JSON.stringify(lat)};
  var lng = !{JSON.stringify(lng)};
  console.log("hi");
script(src='/javascripts/script.js')
```

The variables pass perfectly, all the console.logs print data out the same way, but for some reason, the layers are not printing visibly onto the leaflet map. I see the map, without any of the zipcode areas filled in. jquery works just fine in the file.  What could be going wrong?  the javascript file the code goes into is wrapped in $(document).ready(function () {}); There are no console errors.

This wont add:

```
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
color: 'red',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Markers are visible / add

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is `mymap` available in the moment you do `addTo(mymap)` (if you do `console.log(mymap)` just before the addTo, is it printed well?)

Comment: it seems i can log the mymap before and after addTo